# Interacting with the cell of a custom jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I created a custom table, with a custom model, a custom cell renderer and a custom cell editor. Every cell of this table is a panel which contains another custom table.
The problem is: (with or without the internal table) to interact with the cell, thus to trigger the event listener of the components in that cell(which is a panel), you need to click the table before.
I imagine it wants you to "enter the table" or select the cell before you can actually interact with its components but this is not functional.
Is there a way to avoid this issue?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  Could you create a [mre] that we can copy into our IDE that demonstrates the problem and describe what you want to happen?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Since you asked there it is. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UudipclQFE9WpvFIzCSJMhO9dxnr0KPv/view?usp=sharing
But it is a long code, also you have to replace the path of three images. If you execute it and try to click on the "Titolo" word it should do a System.out.println but it won't execute unless you click a couple times. Same when hovering the ball image in the bottom right corner, it appears a text. I hope you will understand at least the problem if not the code.

Comment: Your code is not well organized.  Which class is the class with the static main method to start the application?  I also see three .form classes, which indicates you used a GUI builder.  Good luck debugging a 12 class application with no package organization.